# Should I insert EVERY useful value into database?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to programming.

Yesterday I was thinking about design a new program database, but I have a problem:

For example, I'm writing a crawler program than record the Kindle ebooks of Amazon,  then I need to create 2 tables:

> 1. item table: record ebooks name, ASIN, url.etc
> 2. price table: base on ASIN, record ebooks today's price, new price and date when the price has changed.

Then at the front-end, actually it needs the `lowest price` of all record time, I was wondering this `lowest price` should record in the price table (just like Excel) or calculate when FE needs?

I know both ways would work, that I just wonder how professional programmer do?

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a good question, with no easy answer... "it depends"

- in general you should avoid duplicating data, this way your database will be consistent. if you need an aggregate - just query for it.
- if you have a lot of queries and a lot of records in the db - you should consider keeping those aggregates and not recalculating them. but now you have to maintain those aggregates either on each insert/update/delete or thru some hourly, daily/nightly jobs. so it is a lot more work for you.

I'd suggest you start with the first approach, and if you hit a perf issue - go to the second